# SQL JOIN with COALESCE in condition is duplicating rows

Tags: sql-server, join, duplicates, left-join, coalesce

I am trying to join two tables together.  The first table contains data records that I do not want to duplicate.  The second table I am joining to the first table to lookup a [value] by a distinct [profileId] and [role].  The [profileId], [role] column in the second table has a unique constraint on the combination, but [role] can sometimes be NULL, in which case I treat that value as the default for that profile.

How can I join these tables together without duplicating the rows, and without using multiple left joins?  My actual query is more complex than the example.

See example below.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE ([profileId] int, [role] int)
DECLARE @temp2 TABLE ([profileId] int, [role] int, [value] nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO @temp ([profileId], [role]) VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO @temp ([profileId], [role]) VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT INTO @temp ([profileId], [role]) VALUES (2, 1)
INSERT INTO @temp ([profileId], [role]) VALUES (2, 2)
INSERT INTO @temp2 ([profileId], [role], [value]) VALUES (1, 1, 'MATCH')
INSERT INTO @temp2 ([profileId], [role], [value]) VALUES (1, NULL, 'DEFAULT1')
INSERT INTO @temp2 ([profileId], [role], [value]) VALUES (2, NULL, 'DEFAULT2')

SELECT
    T1.[profileId],
    T1.[role],
    T2.value
FROM
    @temp T1
    JOIN @temp2 T2 ON T1.profileId = T2.profileId AND COALESCE(T2.[role], T1.[role]) = T1.[role]
```

This gives me (and I understand why)

```
================================
| profileId | role  |  value   |
================================
|     1     |   1   |  MATCH   |
--------------------------------
|     1     |   1   | DEFAULT1 |
--------------------------------
|     1     |   2   | DEFAULT1 |
--------------------------------
|     2     |   1   | DEFAULT2 |
--------------------------------
|     2     |   2   | DEFAULT2 |
================================
```

While I want

```
================================
| profileId | role  |  value   |
================================
|     1     |   1   |  MATCH   |
--------------------------------
|     1     |   2   | DEFAULT1 |
--------------------------------
|     2     |   1   | DEFAULT2 |
--------------------------------
|     2     |   2   | DEFAULT2 |
================================
```

Comment: Your default value is in the database or can you use a `CASE` to get it?

Comment: Will there be multiple NULL `role` in `@temp2` ?

Comment: @FelixPamittan Yes, according to comment in my answer. There is also some `profileID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `APPLY` and `TOP`:

```
SELECT
    t.profileId,
    t.role,
    x.value
FROM @temp t
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 value
    FROM @temp2
    WHERE
        profileId = t.profileId
        AND (role = t.role OR role IS NULL)
    ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN role IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
)x
```

Answer (score 4):

This SQL works fine:

```
SELECT
    T1.[role],
    Value = coalesce(max(nullif(T2.value,'DEFAULT')),'DEFAULT')
FROM
    @temp T1
    JOIN @temp2 T2 ON COALESCE(T2.[role], T1.[role]) = T1.[role]
group by
    T1.[role]
;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know the `DEFAULT` value use `left join`.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc719/4)**

```
SELECT
    T1.[role],
    COALESCE(T2.value, 'DEFAULT') as value
FROM
    temp T1
LEFT JOIN temp2 T2 
       ON T1.[role] = T2.[role];
```

Otherwise

```
SELECT
    T1.[role],
    COALESCE(T2.value, (SELECT value 
                        FROM temp2 
                        WHERE role is NULL and temp2.profileID = T1.profileID)) as value
FROM
    temp T1
LEFT JOIN temp2 T2 
       ON T1.[role] = T2.[role]
      AND T1.[profileID] = T2.[profileID]
       ;
```

Comment: The [value]s are user editable, so I do not know the DEFAULT.  Also, I will modify the definition of @temp2 to it is clear there are many DEFAULT values (based on a profileID).

Comment: Then use second version.